# Copy same selection in several sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA macro:

```
Sub test()
For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Range("J1:Q300").Copy
Range("A301:H601").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next
End Sub
```

The idea is to copy the range "J1:Q300" to "A301:H601" in each of the 100 sheets in my Excel file. The macro above does not give me any error message but only seems to run in the first sheet.

Do you have any idea what might be the mistake in my code?

Comment: you do have the line of `Dim wks As Worksheet` right ?

Comment: Hi Shai, no I forgot it but although I put it now it still does not work. It seems that it only runs in the sheet which is selected in the moment I start the macro.

Comment: see answer below, you need to add need to add `wks.Range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the current **wks** object to your Range:

```
Sub test()

Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Range("J1:Q300").Copy
    wks.Range("A301:H601").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next wks

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just use Range(), you will always refer to the current active worksheet.
You have to either change the current active worksheet or just be more specific by supplying wks.Range():

```
Sub test()
  For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Range("J1:Q300").Copy
    wks.Range("A301:H601").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Next
End Sub
```